# Set up proper programming environment

Tags: linux, linux-mint, c++, access-control

I'm starting to think how to set up the most convenient environment for programming, with the following conditions. I run Linux Mint 14.

1. I've got a computer at work but would like to have access to my code from home computer and notebook.
2. I'd like to have an opportunity to roll back any changes I do in case I break the code, that is having several versions of each project...
3. At the moment I use C++, Python and R, but it would be nice to have it not dependent on languages.
4. Security is important and the stuff I'm doing is definitely not open source.
5. I will be the only person working on my code so collaboration tools are not important.

I'm sure my question is not unique, but I struggle with finding keywords to find what I need. There is no problem in terms of IDE choice etc, the question is really about file system set up, access and version management.

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you need. For (2), use the keywords `source control` or `revision control` to find solutions. Popular ones are [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Comment: Setup a secure system (hardended distribution of GNU/Linux?) which you can securely connect to (VPN?), install all compiler and interpreters you need on it, install git on it to be able to version control your project.

Comment: @JosephR., better try [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) (aka `hg`) for version control, forget about SVN. (My favorite is git, but hg is reputed to be somewhat easier to use). Packages are surely available in your distribution. For IDE, emacs or xemacs are somewhat of a swiss army knife, with tools for all languages you'll ever hear about. _Do not_ cobble up a work environment with self-compiled pieces, use what your distribution provides. Anything else is just inviting endless grief. Consider switching to your principal deployment environment, you _will_ need to have it at hand.

Comment: 3 votes git ;) http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started I'd never set up a VCS before, I did not think it was hard.  Great tool.  I even use it to make coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest installing Git, and possibly, encrypting your hard drive (or at least your home partition).